# MPI_Recv is not receiving the entire message

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing

After MPI_Recv, only the first index of the array is filled and the rest of th eelements are remaining '0'. When I print the Array before sending, the elements are non-zero. But after receiving, except for the first one, all others are zero.

I have checked the size of the array and the datatype.

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your code, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, please supply us with the code.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are missing a pair of braces on line 42.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the 'count' argument in MPI_Recv is correctly indicating the total elements of the array being sent and received. I had the same problem which got rectified when I accurately specified the number of elements in the array. Here is the syntax:
int MPI_Recv(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source, int tag,
             MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status)